# linear transformation $\phi:\mathbb{R}^3 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^4$ which map the following vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Is there a linear transformation $\phi:\mathbb{R}^3 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^4$ which map the following vectors

$\begin {pmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \\ 2 \end{pmatrix} \mapsto \begin {pmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \\2\end{pmatrix}, \begin {pmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix} \mapsto \begin {pmatrix} -1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \\1\end{pmatrix}, \begin {pmatrix} 1 \\ 2 \\ 2 \end{pmatrix} \mapsto \begin {pmatrix} 0 \\ 2 \\ 2 \\3\end{pmatrix}$

My idea so far:

(i) Writing $e_1,e_2,e_3$ as linear combination of $\begin {pmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \\ 2 \end{pmatrix} ,\begin {pmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix},\begin {pmatrix} 1 \\ 2 \\ 2 \end{pmatrix}$

$\begin {pmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \\ 0\end{pmatrix} = 0u_1+2u_2-1u_3 = 0\begin {pmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \\ 2 \end{pmatrix} +2\begin {pmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}-1 \begin {pmatrix} 1 \\ 2 \\ 2 \end{pmatrix}$

$\begin {pmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \\ 0\end{pmatrix} = -\frac{1}{2}\begin {pmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \\ 2 \end{pmatrix} +0 \begin {pmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix} + \frac{1}{2} \begin {pmatrix} 1 \\ 2 \\ 2 \end{pmatrix}$

$\begin {pmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \\ 1\end{pmatrix} = +\frac{1}{2}\begin {pmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \\ 2 \end{pmatrix} -1 \begin {pmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix} + \frac{1}{2} \begin {pmatrix} 1 \\ 2 \\ 2 \end{pmatrix}$

(ii) Calculating $f\begin {pmatrix} x \\ y \\ z\end{pmatrix}$

$f\begin {pmatrix} x \\ y \\ z\end{pmatrix} = f(xe_1+ye_2+ze_3)=xf(e_1)+yf(e_2)+zf(e_3)=xf(2u_2-1u_3)-yf(-\frac{1}{2}u_1+\frac{1}{2}u_3)+zf(\frac{1}{2}u_1-u_2+\frac{1}{2}u_3)=x\begin {pmatrix} -2 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\-1\end{pmatrix}+y\begin {pmatrix} -1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \\1\end{pmatrix}+z\begin {pmatrix} -1 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\3\end{pmatrix}$

Well, if i put it to the test, it seems to be incorrect, but why? Is my idea to approach the problem at least correct?

I finally found my mistake, i've just miscounted myself in the last step. It's

$f\begin {pmatrix} x \\ y \\ z\end{pmatrix} = x\begin {pmatrix} -2 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\-1\end{pmatrix}+y\begin {pmatrix} -\frac{1}{2} \\ \frac{1}{2} \\ \frac{1}{2} \\ \frac{1}{2}\end{pmatrix}+z\begin {pmatrix} -\frac{3}{2} \\ \frac{1}{2} \\ \frac{1}{2} \\ \frac{3}{2}\end{pmatrix}$

Comment: I did, take a look at my last step, i just didn't want to write it so much in detail

Comment: Here's one way to think of this problem. Are the three input vectors linearly independent? If they are, then you can conclude there is such a linear transformation. If they aren't, then what is that combination? The outputs must have the same linear combination law, and if so, then there is such a linear transformation. And if not, then there isn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The linear transformation you're looking for is 
$\begin{pmatrix}
-2 & -0.5 & 1.5\\
0 & 0.5 & 0.5\\
0 & 0.5 & 0.5\\
-1 & 0.5 & 1.5\\
\end{pmatrix}$

Your idea was correct, but let's look at what you did:

Step 1: You expressed the standard vectors $e_1, e_2, e_3$ through the given vectors $u_1, u_2, u_3$. So basically you have moved from standard basis to the basis given by $u_1, u_2, u_3$.

Step 2: You express the image of the standard basis vectors through the images of $u_1, u_2, u_3$, which I will call $v_1, v_2, v_3$. **We are now in the basis $v_1, v_2, v_3$!**

Step 3 (which you are missing): Express $v_1, v_2, v_3$ in terms of the standard basis $e_1, e_2, e_3, e_4$. The coefficients you get now are exactly those in the matrix.

So in conclusion, your transformation was not wrong - it was, however, with respect to the wrong basis in your image space.

Hope this helped :)